# Blazor Server auth with jwt

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have been trying for a few days to do client-side persistence token authorization. The problem is that we essentially cannot use IJSRunrime when a user request comes in to check his authentication, because ServerRendering does not run before initialization on the client. I also tried to use cookies in order to save them in the request, but we cannot do this either due to the fact that the request has already been started, for example, in the same MVC, we can do this without problems.

Detailed errors:
IJSRunrime - "JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time"
Cookie - "headers are read-only, response has already started"

I create this code for example and my question - How save token on the client side?

UPD: I don't want to reload SPA application, [some examples](https://blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/36) do it and I can't use HttpContext.SignIn because have Cookie error.

```
@page "/SignIn"

<EditForm EditContext="@editContext" OnValidSubmit="SendRequestSubmit" class="auth__form">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

    <div class="auth__item">
        <h4 class="auth__actions-title actions-title">Email<span>*</span></h4>
        <InputText @bind-Value="signInRequest.Email" class="input-actions" />
    </div>

    <div class="auth__item">
        <h4 class="auth__actions-title actions-title">Password<span>*</span></h4>
        <InputText @bind-Value="signInRequest.Password" type="password" class="input-actions" />
    </div>

    <button class="auth__confirm actions-btn btn" disabled="@sendRequestLoading">
        Sign In
    </button>
</EditForm>

@code {

    // it is code for example
    private async void SendRequestSubmit()
    {
        var auth = accountSerrvice.auth(Email, Password);

        if(auth == true && auth.Token != null)
        {
            // Save auth.Token in the client side
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Test error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/server/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-5.0), in the Blazor server application, to get the JWT token, you could use the httpclient to call the API method. Then, to pass the token between components, you can define a scoped token provider service to store the token.